# Sequelize Op.overlap for array of strings

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have one table which has an array of strings called `tags`.

and the data looks like this:

{ id: 1, tags: ['football', 'basketball'] }, { id: 2, tags: ['football', 'hockey'] }

The user can input several strings to find all records which contain at least one query in the tags field.

The example of queries: ['football', 'baseball']

To implement this, I tried to use `Op.overlap` but it doesn't work.

```
db.Submission.findAll({
  where: {
    tags: {
      [Op.overlap]: queries, // ['football', 'baseball']
    }
  }
});
```

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: you got any error ?

Answer (score 0):

Operator `Op.overlap` should work. NOTE: This is a [Postgres-only Range Operator](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#postgres-only-range-operators)

Environment:

- `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`
- postgres:9.6

E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, Op } from 'sequelize';

class Submission extends Model {}
Submission.init(
  {
    tags: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
  },
  { sequelize, tableName: 'submissions' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await Submission.bulkCreate([
      { tags: ['football', 'basketball'] },
      { tags: ['football', 'hockey'] },
      { tags: ['a', 'b'] },
    ]);

    // test
    const queries = ['football', 'baseball'];
    const data = await Submission.findAll({
      where: {
        tags: {
          [Op.overlap]: queries,
        },
      },
      raw: true,
    });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "submissions" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "submissions" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "submissions" ("id"   SERIAL , "tags" VARCHAR(255)[], PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'submissions' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "submissions" ("id","tags") VALUES (DEFAULT,ARRAY['football','basketball']::VARCHAR(255)[]),(DEFAULT,ARRAY['football','hockey']::VARCHAR(255)[]),(DEFAULT,ARRAY['a','b']::VARCHAR(255)[]) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "tags" FROM "submissions" AS "Submission" WHERE "Submission"."tags" && ARRAY['football','baseball']::VARCHAR(255)[];
[
  { id: 1, tags: [ 'football', 'basketball' ] },
  { id: 2, tags: [ 'football', 'hockey' ] }
]
```

The data records in the database:

[image]